# Interpreting p values for Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, representing p values afterwards

Tags: python, statistics, data-visualization, distribution

I have a set of distributions that I generate based on a parameter. What I want is to look at adjacent distributions and generate `K-S` test values for them. Later, I also want to generalize this to a 3D plot so I can see distribution similarity for `non-adjacent` distributions, but I'm having some trouble getting the initial test code working properly.

Here is a sample of the type of visualization I want to do.

```
rvars = []
for n in range(20):
    rvars.append(np.random.normal(n*10,n,100))
    #rvars.append(np.random.poisson(n*10,1000))
    
rvars_means = [np.mean(k) for k in rvars]
rvars_std = [np.std(k) for k in rvars]
    
ks_test_p = []
ks_test_statistic = []
for p in range(20-1):
    dvals,pvals = stats.ks_2samp(rvars[p], rvars[p+1]) 
    ks_test_p.append(pvals)
    ks_test_statistic.append(dvals)
    
plt.figure(figsize = (12,4))

plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.errorbar(range(20),rvars_means,yerr= rvars_std)
plt.title('Means, errorbar is std')
plt.xlabel('trial')
plt.ylabel('mean value')

plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.plot(range(19),ks_test_p)
plt.title('p value ks test')
plt.xlabel('adj trial')
plt.ylabel('ks p val')

plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.plot(range(19),ks_test_statistic)
plt.title('statistic value ks test')
plt.xlabel('adj trial')
plt.ylabel('ks statistic')
plt.show()
```

[image: Results from sample code]

Now, this is giving me somewhat unexpected results. Because the standard deviations are overlapping, I would expect the p values for the K-S test to be much higher as the adj trial goes up. The same effect persists regardless of what distribution I use.

The interpretation I want to arrive at is essentially that the more overlap there is between two distributions, the less likely I could take a measurement and tell which distribution it came from. So if I had a measurement and the distribution options are trial 5 and trial 15, I could choose a distribution with high confidence. But, the same wouldn't be true if I was choosing between distributions corresponding to trial 15 and trial 16.

In terms of visualizing this in 3D, I was considering a square color plot, in this case, `20x20`, with the color corresponding to how differentiable the distributions are. I think this is a non-ideal way to represent the data though, so I was interested in suggestions on how to better visualize these. Looking at the `errorbars` is good for a rough sense, but doesn't have the specificity that something like a `p-value` would have.